# cross-product sign in surface integrals

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals

I read in some lecture notes I've found online that, when calculating the cross product in a surface integral when it comes to flux, I need to check to see if the vector that results from this cross product has the same direction of the unit vector that informs the surface's orientation. Otherwise, the magnitude of the flux will be correct, but the sign will not. This makes sense, but I don't get how I should check if the cross product has the right direction. I mean, perhaps is ok when the parameters are in a plane, because you just have to apply the right hand rule, but when, for example, the surface is a sphere of radius a, and the parameters are phi and theta, how am I supposed to verify this?

Comment: If you use theta as the polar angle and phi as the azimuthal angle then the right hand rule will help you determine orientation of the resulting normal with convention that the outward pointing normal of a closed surface is positive.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand how to use the right hand rule when we are talking about angles not vectors

Comment: The angles themselves have the equivalent of a unit vector just like the radial one does, if theta is the polar angle then $\hat{\theta} \times \hat{\phi}=\hat{r}$ the positively outward directed normal. It's a bit difficult to illustrate without a good drawing

Comment: https://goo.gl/images/ZF15c2 this is what I'm attempting to describe where the $e_i$ are the unit vectors